# How to connect with container inside VM

Tags: docker, ssh

I have issue to connect from my local machine through SSH with Docker container on which I have openssh-server installed and exposed on port 22 (default for openssh server) and this container is on virtual machine.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest 

RUN apt-get -y update 
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-server 

EXPOSE 22
```

After expose 22 in dockerfile shouldn't I be able to connect for example through `ssh://user@vmIP:22`?

Comment: Please, post you dockerfile.

Comment: I edited your post for you. The **dockerfile** apparently looks good, I cannot try it now, but I suggest you to run it, enter the docker image by `docker exec -ti <<CONTAINER_NAME>> bash` , search for the `sshd` logs, and look at them while try to  connect to.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca I can connect through ssh from virtual machine into docker but I can't connect from my local machine with docker.

Comment: Some more details about the VM setup would be helpful.  Dockerfile `EXPOSE` does almost nothing and you generally need to run a container with a `docker run -p` option to make it accessible from outside of Docker (for instance, from another host or VM).

Comment: @DavidMaze So in the network configuration I set the network to NAT and second one to bridge mode. Here you have a comand which I use to run container: `docker run -d -P  --rm test`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not ideal to connect via SSH to a running docker container, read this so you can understand why https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/ssh-into-a-docker-container-how-to-execute-your-commands, now if you really want to do that, the EXPOSE instruction is a way to document to the Dockerfile maintainer or another dev that you are most likely to have a service running on that port, it will not map that port to the host were you are running the container.

In order to map a port from the container to the VM you can do this:

```
#Build the container in the same directory where the Dockerfile is located
docker build . -t mycontainer:latest
#Run it mapping port 22 to the VMs port 2222 in detached mode
docker run -d -p 2222:22 mycontainer:latest
```

Now, you have port 2222 of the VM mapped to the running container port 22, so `ssh://user@vmip:222` would work